# main function not waiting for channel read before exiting?

Tags: go, goroutine, channel

Consider the following attempt to implement [Dining Philosophers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dining_philosophers_problem) with Go routines and channels.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func philos(id int, left, right, plate chan bool) {
    fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d wants to eat\n", id) 
    <-left
    <-right
    plate <- true
    left <- true
    right <- true
    fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d finished eating\n", id) 
}

func main() {
    const numPhilos = 5 
    var forks [numPhilos]chan bool
    for i := 0; i < numPhilos; i++ {
        forks[i] = make(chan bool, 1)
        forks[i] <- true
    }   
    plates := make(chan bool)
    for i := 0; i < numPhilos; i++ {
        go philos(i, forks[(i-1+numPhilos)%numPhilos], forks[(i+numPhilos)%numPhilos], plates)
    }   
    for i := 0; i < numPhilos; i++ {
        <-plates
    }   
}
```

Sometimes this works as expected, i.e. all philosophers eat, e.g.:

```
Philosopher # 4 wants to eat
Philosopher # 3 wants to eat
Philosopher # 2 wants to eat
Philosopher # 1 wants to eat
Philosopher # 4 finished eating
Philosopher # 3 finished eating
Philosopher # 2 finished eating
Philosopher # 1 finished eating
Philosopher # 0 wants to eat
Philosopher # 0 finished eating
```

However, sometimes, one (or more) philosophers are missed (e.g. Philosopher #0, did not eat in the following case):

```
Philosopher # 4 wants to eat
Philosopher # 1 wants to eat
Philosopher # 3 wants to eat
Philosopher # 2 wants to eat
Philosopher # 4 finished eating
Philosopher # 0 wants to eat
Philosopher # 2 finished eating
Philosopher # 1 finished eating
Philosopher # 3 finished eating
```

**Question is**: *why* does this happen?

What I already know:

1. The program will exit if the `main` go routine finished (even if some other routines are still running).
2. A go routine will block if it tries to read from a channel, and that channel is empty (i.e. no-one wrote to it previously).

Now, `main` tries to read 5 times from the channel `plates`, therefore it should not terminate until the `philos` routine has run five times. But it seems it somehow still manages to terminate before doing that. Am I missing something? (It seems that `plates` was read only 4 times.)

**EDIT**: Ok, after thinking about it a bit more, I came to the conclusion, that maybe the `philos` routine does always run 5 times, however, it can be interrupted **before** having the time to print that the philosopher ate. Indeed, if I change the order as follows, it seems to be working always:

```
func philos(id int, left, right, plate chan bool) {
    fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d wants to eat\n", id) 
    <-left
    <-right
    left <- true
    right <- true
    fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d finished eating\n", id) 
    plate <- true
}
```

Still, it would be great if someone could validate this explanation :)

Comment: @downvoter: care to elaborate what is the problem with this question? Maybe I can try to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in stdout isn't the same as what's happening. Sometimes, `main` receives from `plates` and then returns before the print statement happens. So:

```
plate <- true
left <- true    // On this line or on
right <- true   // this line, main receives from plate and then returns before
fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d finished eating\n", id) // this line executes
```

Because concurrency isn't deterministic, this doesn't happen every time. Sometimes the print happens before `main` returns, sometimes it doesn't. That doesn't mean the channel read isn't happening.

Comment: Thanks, I just arrived to this conclusion too after looking at the code again :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the channel is read 5 times, but since the main function is only waiting for the channel to be read for the 5th time, it exits before the philos function gets to this line:

```
fmt.Printf("Philosopher # %d finished eating\n", id)`
```

In order for it to print this correctly, you would need to run this line before you write to the plate channel.